# How to delete entities with GORM(Grails) and HQL(Hibernate) using executeUpdate()

Tags: sql, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

In my usecase I want to delete all entries of `LabelTestEntity` which are associated to a specific testEntity (passed as an argument from outside) and to any label which is of type `SUB_LABEL`. To do that I use grails `executeUpdate()` method which should in my opinion look like this:

```
LabelTestEntity.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM LabelTestEntity WHERE testEntity= :TEST and label.labelType= :TYP", 
  [TEST: testEntity, TYP: Label.Type.SUB_LABEL])
```

Unfortunately this causes an SQL Syntax Error:

```
Error |
2014-12-17 16:14:06,130 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] ERROR util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - Syntax error in SQL statement "DELETE FROM LABEL_TEST_ENTITY CROSS[*] JOIN LABEL LABEL1_ WHERE TEST_ENTITY_NAME=? AND TEST_ENTITY_SPEC_PATH=? AND TEST_ENTITY_SPEC_FILE_NAME=? AND LABEL_TYPE=? "; SQL statement:
delete from label_test_entity cross join label label1_ where test_entity_name=? and test_entity_spec_path=? and test_entity_spec_file_name=? and label_type=? [42000-176]
Error |
2014-12-17 16:14:06,210 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - JdbcSQLException occurred when processing request: [POST] /cartoapp/mapping/groupedReassignOfSubLabels
Syntax error in SQL statement "DELETE FROM LABEL_TEST_ENTITY CROSS[*] JOIN LABEL LABEL1_ WHERE TEST_ENTITY_NAME=? AND TEST_ENTITY_SPEC_PATH=? AND TEST_ENTITY_SPEC_FILE_NAME=? AND LABEL_TYPE=? "; SQL statement:
delete from label_test_entity cross join label label1_ where test_entity_name=? and test_entity_spec_path=? and test_entity_spec_file_name=? and label_type=? [42000-176]. Stacktrace follows:
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "DELETE FROM LABEL_TEST_ENTITY CROSS[*] JOIN LABEL LABEL1_ WHERE TEST_ENTITY_NAME=? AND TEST_ENTITY_SPEC_PATH=? AND TEST_ENTITY_SPEC_FILE_NAME=? AND LABEL_TYPE=? "; SQL statement:
delete from label_test_entity cross join label label1_ where test_entity_name=? and test_entity_spec_path=? and test_entity_spec_file_name=? and label_type=? [42000-176]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:344)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:178)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:154)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:190)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.getSyntaxError(Parser.java:517)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:246)
```

Sources of examples: [HQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/batch.html#batch-direct) and [GORM](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/executeUpdate.html)

What have I tried so far:

1. Removing the `FROM`. **Result**: Is just syntactic sugar and is always used internally
2. Using Aliases. **Result**: Same error same behavior
3. Trying the same query with only one condition.

   `LabelTestEntity.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM LabelTestEntity WHERE testEntity= :TEST", [TEST: testEntity])`

   **Result**: **This works** and all `LabelTestEntity` for a particular test are deleted no matter which type of label they are associated with.

This leads me to the conclusion that adding a second condition using `AND` to the `WHERE` block causes the syntax error. Can someone suggest or does someone know - what is the issue here?

----EDIT----
Here is what the relation between domain classes looks like:

```
class LabelTestEntity implements Serializable {
  Label label
  TestEntity testEntity

  static mapping = {
    id composite: ['label', 'testEntity']
  }
}

class Label {

  //0 FOR MAIN_LABEL 1 FOR SUB_LABEL, 2 FOR TECH_LABEL
  enum Type {
      MAIN_LABEL, SUB_LABEL, TECH_LABEL
      private final int value;

      private Type() {
        this.value = ordinal();
      }
  }

  String name 
  Application application
  String description
  Type labelType

  static constraints = {
    name blank: false
    application blank: false
    description nullable : true
  }

  static mapping = {
    labelType enumType:"ordinal"
   }
}
```

Comment: it looks like you forgot to declare the 'label' alias in your query. Try LabelTestEntity.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM LabelTestEntity as label WHERE testEntity= :TEST and label.labelType= :TYP", 
  [TEST: testEntity, TYP: Label.Type.SUB_LABEL]). Now I'm not sure what is your testEntity and don't know the relations between your classes, so...

Comment: I added the code of the domain classes to make it more clear. `label` is a property of the domain class LabelTestEntity which is why I access it directly.

Answer (score 0):

So after some struggling we found out that `DELETE` does not support joins, but trying to access the properties of the associated `Label` entity is converted internally into a join.

The solution is to do a pre-selection of `LabelTestEntity`s to delete - and then delete these entities.

```
  LabelTestEntity.executeUpdate("DELETE LabelTestEntity lte "
    + "WHERE lte.id IN ( SELECT lte2.id FROM LabelTestEntity lte2 WHERE lte2.testEntity= :TEST "
    + "AND lte2.label.labelType= :TYP)", [TEST: testEntity, TYP: labelType])
```

To make the pre-selection more lightweight and to delete only by ID it is necessary to remove the static mapping of 'LabelTestEntity' which changes the way in which IDs are generated.